# Why is text rendered incorrectly after converting iOS app to Arm64?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-rendering, arm64

I have an iOS app that I converted to suppport Arm64. My initial conversion steps are:

1) Change target Architectures $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) to $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

2) Fix enum definitions:

```
// before
typedef enum {
    MyEnumValue1,
    MyEnumValue2
} MyEnum;

// after
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyEnum) {
    MyEnumValue1,
    MyEnumValue2
}
```

3) Fix incorrect type in `stringWithFormat`:

```
// before
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The value is %d", someValue];

// after
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The value is %lu", someValue];
```

That's pretty much it. The problem I ran into is that in some views, text is now rendered incorrectly. None of the code around the views that render the text has changed and I'm not doing any custom text drawing. In the example pics below the text is rendered by a `UIButton`.

## Text rendered by `UIButton` before conversion to Arm64

[image: Before conversion to Arm64]

## Text rendered by `UIButton` after conversion to Arm64

[image: After conversion to Arm64]

I can go back and forth from the commit before the conversion to the commit after the conversion and reproduce this. I closely scanned the diff and don't see any clear contributing factors.

## QUESTIONS

1. What could cause this?
2. Any ideas on how to debug this and/or what to look for?
3. Even better, anybody know why this is happenening?

Comment: can you provide a minimal sample? it is not in the code above I'd say

Comment: I'm happy to provide some code. Not sure what to show however. Do you want the `UIButton` configuration?

Comment: yes a small working project that shows the error.. don't know if it helps but Id like to look at it :)

Comment: I'll try. The app in question is fairly large. I'll try to extract relevant code and we'll see if I can create a small sample project that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around to creating a sample app that exhibited this behavior. In the process, I found the problem. One of my custom `UITableViewCell` classes is used as a superclass for a number of cell types within the app. This cell had the `cell.layer.shouldRasterize` setting set to YES. While this appeared to work fine in the 32-bit version of the app, it caused problems in the ARM64 version. It's also likely the wrong thing to do in any case as cell rendering performance is adversely affected. These cells have shadow effects around various edges which is why I had set `shouldRasterize` to begin with.

There's no way anyone here would have been able to help me w/o the sample app so I appreciate any time any of you spent investigating. Had I not figured it out I would have posted the sample app.